# For $f:N\rightarrow N$, where $f(x)=x-(-1)^x$, then prove that $f$ is one-one and onto

Tags: calculus, functions

Taking the first derivative

$$f’(x)=-x(-1)^{x-1}$$

Depending on the value of $x$, the slope of the graph changes from positive to negative. Thus it cannot be one-one

However, if we simplify the original function

For $x$ is even
$$f(x)=x+1$$

For $x$ is odd

$$f(x)=x-1$$ which looks like a one-one function. Which is the right one?

Comment: How can you diifferentiate a sequence ?

Comment: The function you mention in the title is not the same as the one in the body. The equation in the title should be $f(x)=x-(-1)^{x+1}$ or $x+(-1)^x$.

Comment: And $f(1)=0\not\in\mathbb{N}$? so how is the function onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,

$$f(2n)=2n-(-1)^{2n}=2n-1$$
$$f(2n+1)=2n+1-(-1)^{2n+1}$$
$$=2n+2=2(n+1)$$

thus

$$f^{-1}(2p+1)=2(p+1)$$
and
$$f^{-1}(2p)=2(p-1)+1=2p-1$$

The antecedents exist and are unique, $ f $ is one to one.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative is not applicable for a function from $\Bbb {N \to N}$ as the domain is not continuous.  The second approach is correct.